How many Key/value pairs can be stored under one secret in Hashicorp vault?
I am going through Vault documentation, and it is unclear to me that how many key/value pairs can be stored under one namespace, one mount point and one secret.
Are the below formulae correct when calculating the total storage size for 100,000 key/value pairs?
Size per version=key size + value size + metadata size
Size per version=100bytes+100bytes+21bytes=221bytes
Total storage size=100,000×Size per version
Total storage size=100,000×221bytes=22,100,000 bytes≈22.1MB

Each version of a key-value v2 (henceforth kv-v2) secret occupies one storage entry. The maximum size of a storage entry depends on your storage backend. The default storage entry limit in Consul is 512KiB, but can be tuned upwards. The default storage entry limit in integrated storage is 1MiB, but can be tuned upward. The integrated storage will chunk entries larger than 512KiB.
Those parameters inform the maximum "object" size depending on the storage backend. With that in mind, we can calculate the maximum amount of data that can be stored in the kv-v2 secret data itself. This information is described in the docs here and states the following:

The maximum size of a single secret version is "slightly less than one storage entry".

Based on the storage limitations described above, this defaults to 512KiB, 1MiB, or a value you have set in Consul or Vault's storage configuration. Secret key-value pairs are converted to JSON, so some of the storage bytes will be taken by the serialization syntax.

Each version of a kv-v2 secret is stored separately.

No need to worry about how many versions fit into a single storage entry—they are stored separately. However, you may be limited by the number of versions you can store due to #3.

Version metadata consumes 21 bytes per version and must fit in a single storage entry, separate from the stored data.

"Separate from the stored data" helps clarify that this does not count towards the storage limit for an individual secret version. This constraint may impose a limit depending on how many versions you expect to use.

Version-agnostic metadata is stored separately

This is user-provided and has some limitations. The documentation does not go into detail about where this is stored.
Your equation may be better expressed as:
Size per version = length(bytes(json.dump(data))
Total storage = (
  100,000 * (
    100 for key 
    + 100 bytes for value 
    + 4 quote chars
    + a semicolon
    + a comma
  ) + {} JSON characters / 1024 / 1024

Total storage = (100,000 * (200 + 6) + 2/ 1024 / 1024 = 19.65MiB
Where data is your key and value pairs dictionary. The JSON syntax and encoding creates some overhead dependent on how much you're serializing. Exact overhead depends on several factors such as whether the data structure is shallow or nested, the data types of the values (dates? numbers? floats?), whether or not you need to base64 encode some binary data before serializing, and so on.
Somewhere around 20MiB seems right for 100,000 key-value pairs where each key and value are 100bytes each and we assume they're strings of single-byte characters. This wouldn't be possible unless you configured your storage backend to allow an entry this size. When using Consul as a backend, this may produce some undesirable performance due to the lack of chunking as described in the documentation.
